# Show $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f(x)|^3 dx =3 \int_{0}^\infty t^2 |\left\{x : f(x)>t \right\}| dt$

Tags: integration, measure-theory

I am studying for a measure theory exam, and I came across the following problem that I am stuck on.

Show $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f(x)|^3 dx =3 \int_{0}^\infty t^2 |\left\{x : f(x)>t \right\}| dt$.

My idea:

$|f(x)|^3=3 \int_{0}^{|f(x)|}t^2dt$.

$\implies \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f(x)|^3 dx= 3\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \int_{0}^{|f(x)|}t^2dt$.

I am stuck after this. I think that I should Fubini's theorem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f(x)|^3dx=3\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\int_0^{|f(x)|}t^2 dt dx=3\int_{\{(t,x)\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}:0\leq t\leq |f(x)|\}}t^2 d(t,x)=3\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\{x:|f(x)|\ge t\}}t^2dxdt=3\int_{\mathbb{R}}t^2\int_{\{x:|f(x)|\ge t\}}dxdt$
Here I used several times Fubini's (or "just" Tonelli's) theorem (check!).
The desired result with $>$ instead of $\ge$ should follow if the graph of $|f|$ has Lebesgue measure $0$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. (Continuity of $f$ should be sufficient for that.)